# Previous PCollection being altered by Pardo despite immutability as stated in docs. Suspected Bug

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am currently coding a streaming pipeline to insert data into Bigtable, but I have encountered a problem which I believe is a bug with Apache Beam, but would like some opinions.
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/
In this documentation, it says that PCollections are immutable, but I have found a case where the PCollection is mutating unexpectedly due to a Pardo function at a branching point causing very unexpected errors, and also these errors occur randomly, not on all entries of data.

I have tested this both in deployment on Google Cloud Dataflow, in a jupyter notebook on Google Cloud and locally on my machine, and the error occurs on all platforms. Therefore, it should be related to the core library but I am not sure hence I am posting it here for people's wisdom.

So here is the code to recreate the problem:

```py
class CreateRawRow(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, data):
        from google.cloud.bigtable.row import DirectRow
        import datetime

        # Convert str to datetime
        convertedTimestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(data['Timestamp'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
        timestamp = convertedTimestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

        row_key = f"a#b#raw#c#{timestamp}"
        direct_row = DirectRow(row_key)
        for key in data:
            cf = "data"
            column = key
            value = str(data[key])
            direct_row.set_cell(
                cf,
                column,
                value,
                convertedTimestamp)

        return [direct_row]

p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
rawdata = p | "Read" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription)
jsonData = (rawdata | "Parse Json" >> beam.Map(json.loads))

jsonData | "Create Row Information" >> beam.ParDo(CreateRawRow())
class ChangeTimestamp(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, data):
        import datetime

        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(data['Timestamp'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
        convertedTimestamp = timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        data["Timestamp"] = convertedTimestamp #Commenting out this line fixes the problem

        yield [data]
changedTimestamp = jsonData | "Change Time stamp" >> beam.ParDo(ChangeTimestamp())

result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

The code above is a stripped down to show the exact line of code that causes the problem.
As you can see in the code above, I have ingested from Pub Sub (it must be ingested from pubsub, if I use beam.Create() to simulate the data coming in, the errors do not occur). I load the data from pubsub using json.loads to turn it into a dictionary. After ingesting from pubsub, I try to create a row for insertion into BigTable using CreateRawRow(). I also create a seperate branch called "Change Time Stamp".

Now, the error I get is

```
ValueError: time data '2021-02-13 20:12:23' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z' [while running 'Create Row Information']
```

Which comes from CreateRawRow

However, I have traced the issue to the ChangeTimestamp class which has the line "data["Timestamp"] = convertedTimestamp". If i comment out these lines, errors disappear. Also if I change the time format to something else, the error follows suit, so it is definitely this line that is the troublemaker.

So my immediate suspicion is that somehow, the previous "jsonData" Pcollection is mutated because of this line in this Pardo. However, this shouldnt be posssible according to the docs. Hence, I would like some opinions, am I doing this wrong or is this a genuine bug? Bear in mind also, this does not happen for every entry on PubSub coming in, and also this does not happen if I use Beam.Create() to simulate the data stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement on PCollection immutability is that DoFns SHOULD not mutate their inputs. In languages like Python where everything is passed by reference and by default mutable (no `const`), this is difficult if not impossible to enforce.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Perhaps the docs should be edited to also reflect this because the statement in this docs is "remember that a PCollection is immutable"

So I suppose the solution to all of this in python is to try to enforce mutability by using tuples ?

Comment: Good points, the docs should be more clear. Do you have some specific pointers/suggestions? (If you feel so inclined, a PR at https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/website/www/site/content/en/documentation would be welcome.) As to immutability, tuples are great, but a tuple of lists or other mutable objects still has the same problem.